# How can I get array parameter value dynamically using groovy in soap UI

Tags: json, rest, groovy, soapui

I have API and lot of parameters there. I am using `context` to get value of particular parameter into groovy script.

But `context` returns me **null** for array parameters or parameters which are based on id.

### **Success**

- context.title
- context.name

### **Failed to get value**

- context.location[] , context.location[id]
- context.department[], context.department[id]

In API, I pass location and department IDs to get data.

For ex : location[id] = 556d6dDRE666deda5c

So how can I get value of parameters using groovy where parameters are either array or has ids.

Comment: Do you mind showing the data and which value you want to access?

Comment: @Rao - Added sample data if that can help.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Would appreciate if the text response can be added, you may keep the structure and put dummy values. Because, solution may vary depends on the response. By the way, what data you want to retrieve? `skills`?

Comment: @Rao-   Yes I want to retrieve skills and location id. location has unique id that's it.

Comment: Can't find `location` in the visible data that you provided. Please add text response so that solution would be tested before answering.

Comment: @Rao - Here it is : location[id] = 556d6dDRE666deda5c

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137450/discussion-between-rao-and-helping-hands).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the below `Script Assertion` based on the data provided.

```
//Check the response is not empty
assert context.response, 'Response is empty or null'

//Define expected values
def expectedLocationId = 'Your value here'
def expectedSkills = ['.NET']

def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(context.response)

log.info "Skills : ${json.data.skills}"

log.info "Location id : ${json.location.id}"

//Assertions:

assert expectedLocationId == json.location.id, 'Location id not matching'
assert expectedSkills == json.data.skills, 'Skills not matching'
```